# Rendering a lit-element in light DOM to use with stripe.js

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, web-component, shadow-dom, lit-element

Stripe.js does not yet support shadow-dom. Using Lit-elements's `createRenderRoot()` [(documentation)](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/templates#specify-the-render-root),[(source)](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/blob/master/src/lib/updating-element.ts#L457-L466)  you can render the template into the element's light DOM by using `return this;` . However this only works if you implement `createRenderRoot()` in all parent elements. Is there a way around this?

Here is my stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ruwkze?file=my-element.js). It only works because I call `createRenderRoot(){ return this; }` on every element.

Comment: in Lit 2 use the `render` method to DOM/aka light-DOM as shown in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69287098/965666 similar approach possible with older versions of Lit/LitElement/lit-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Morbidick's [stripe-elements](https://github.com/morbidick/stripe-elements) talks directly with the Stripe token backend. It doesnt use stripe.js so it doesn't have the same Shadow DOM restrictions. But tokens come with their own issues.

Bennypowers's [stripe-elements](https://github.com/bennypowers/stripe-elements) offers a custom element wrapper for Stripe.js that works in shadow DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `document.getElementById(...)`. When using shadowRoot, you should use:

```
this.shadowRoot.getElementById(...)
```

So, to mount idealBank, you could use:

```
// Add an instance of the idealBank Element into the `ideal-bank-element` <div>.
const bankElement = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#ideal-bank-element');
idealBank.mount(bankElement);
```

The stripe.js lib may or may not work well with shadowRoot. If the lib uses document.getElementById or some other root-document construct, it may fail.

Comment: Stripe.js doesn't work with shadowRoot. createRenderRoot() allows the element to render in the normal DOM tree, so document.getElementById() does work, but I have to render all the parent elements in normal DOM and I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: mount works with a dom element as well... so there should be no need for document.getElementById