# Rendering child elements with LitElement ( light DOM and slots )

Tags: children, lit-element, slot

I'm trying to write a LitElement web component that will wrap unknown child content.  I've read about slots ( https://lit-element.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.4/docs/templates/slots/ ) but it only seems to work for the shadow DOM.  I'm using the light DOM.  In React, the properties come with a special 'children' property to render the child tree.  But how can this be achieved in LitElement in the light DOM?  Even though the documentation above talks about the light DOM, it's not working in my case.

UPDATE:  I'm getting around this by adding a property of type 'TemplateResult' to my element and passing in the content as a property.  But not sure this is the best solution.

Comment: Can you post your code and any error message please?

Comment: By the way the official is here https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/templates#slots

Answer (score 0):

In light Dom your render() will modify the previus childNodes your component had before mounted.

One approach could be save whatever was before [connectedCallback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) is called.

Consider the following example

```js
export class Text extends LitElement {
  createRenderRoot() {
    return this;
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    this._textOverride = this.innerText.trim();
  }
  render() {
    return html`
      <strong>${this._textOverride}</strong>
    `;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

to render elements directly in the DOM tree (aka light-dom) in Lit version 2 use `render` exported from `lit/html.js` (lit imports it from it's version of lit-html, for details see https://lit.dev/):

```
<script type=module>
// or from 'lit' and 'lit/html.js' respectively:
import { LitElement, html } from 'https://unpkg.com/lit?module';
import { render } from 'https://unpkg.com/lit/html.js?module';

class EgTime extends LitElement{
    connectedCallback(){
        super.connectedCallback();
        render(this.time(), this);
    }
    time(){
        const now = new Date();
        return html`<time datetime="${ now.toISOString() }">time ${ now.toLocaleTimeString() } ${ now.toLocaleDateString() }</time>`;
    }
    render(){
        return html`<hr> ::slotted( <slot>~~~</slot> ) <hr>`;
    }
}

customElements.define('eg-time', EgTime);
</script>
<eg-time style="position:fixed;inset:auto 3rem 3rem auto;background:#fff;padding:1rem;border:1px solid #000;">
...
</eg-time>
```